# struts2 prevent other users from performing an action

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, struts2

hello i am trying to write a web application with struts 2 the problem is that i am having an action like this http://localhost:8080/Onda_vol/suprimer?id=14
which allows user to delete  a row from SQL with the id= 14 
i am using session that doesn't allow people to enter the application with no permission

for example if i enter to  http://localhost:8080/Onda_vol/index.jsp it will redirect me to  http://localhost:8080/Onda_vol/login.jsp and will ask for username and password but the but when some one enter to http://localhost:8080/Onda_vol/suprimer?id=14 it redirects him to http://localhost:8080/Onda_vol/login.jsp but the row with the id=14 get deleted 
how can i prevent this from happening 
please don't tell me to use post instead of get cause the action is written like this

`<th><a class="btn btn-danger" href="suprimer?id=<s:property value="id_vol" />"> suprimer</a></th>`
[image]
ps: suprimer means delete

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: -_- what do u think its about -_-

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **Interceptors**. See https://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html on how to use them.